# Long Url values not submitting in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, urlhelper

I want to pass some value to one website to another website through URL and store the values in session in other website. So I need to pass all the data regarding that website.

Here is my error message below:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected
Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
Line Number: 542
```

Comment: You may get this error when you are dealing with lot of variables and trying to passing those variable to header and by a mistake you have new line in your header string.

Comment: No there is no any new line

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is too many variables. There is probably a new line in one of your variables. Try encoding your URL first and check again.